# How do i retain or remove the predictor variables from the logit model?

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

1. Assume my data set has 15 predictor variables.while building a model using logistic regression, if i want to knock the variables off the model based on its significance/impact on the model.
   Do i have to remove the predictors only when the p- value is less than 0.05?.Or do i need to consider other parameters before adding or removing a predictor variable from the glm equation? Because i was told that, Ultimately i  should be building a model with few predictor as it would be easy while implementing the model at customer's place.

please find below the model summary and help me in understand how do i remove the variables based on AIC and p values.

Call:

```
glm(formula = TARGET ~ duration + cons.price.idx + cons.conf.idx + 
    emp.var.rate + poutcome + contact + job, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = Training)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.9536  -0.3148  -0.1601  -0.1029   3.5807
```

Coefficients:

```
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -1.331e+02  7.048e+00 -18.886  < 2e-16 ***
duration             8.333e-03  1.782e-04  46.764  < 2e-16 ***
cons.price.idx       1.396e+00  7.582e-02  18.408  < 2e-16 ***
cons.conf.idx        6.505e-02  5.673e-03  11.466  < 2e-16 ***
emp.var.rate        -9.507e-01  3.015e-02 -31.538  < 2e-16 ***
poutcomenonexistent  4.426e-01  8.802e-02   5.029 4.94e-07 ***
poutcomesuccess      2.054e+00  1.263e-01  16.267  < 2e-16 ***
contacttelephone    -9.380e-01  8.402e-02 -11.164  < 2e-16 ***
jobblue-collar      -4.662e-01  8.778e-02  -5.311 1.09e-07 ***
jobentrepreneur     -1.287e-01  1.623e-01  -0.793   0.4279    
jobhousemaid        -2.577e-01  2.018e-01  -1.277   0.2015    
jobmanagement       -2.383e-01  1.176e-01  -2.026   0.0428 *  
jobretired           2.729e-01  1.222e-01   2.234   0.0255 *  
jobself-employed    -2.554e-02  1.562e-01  -0.164   0.8701    
jobservices         -2.343e-01  1.086e-01  -2.156   0.0311 *  
jobstudent           3.178e-01  1.486e-01   2.139   0.0324 *  
jobtechnician       -2.138e-02  8.854e-02  -0.241   0.8092    
jobunemployed       -9.136e-02  1.890e-01  -0.483   0.6288  


---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 14499  on 20592  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  8568  on 20575  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8604
```

my question is , when do i say AIC value is good? and of what basis do i remove the variables to maintain least no of variables.

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

Comment: Just in case nobody (can) answer here, try http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are describing is known as *stepwise logistic regression* and has received a substantial amount of criticism due to its poor performance. Instead of using p-values it is recommended to consider [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) or [SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion). A nice explanation with many examples in SAS is given in http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p222-26.pdf

Comment: To add to this, AIC is nice because it balances model fit with the number of variables (we want the best model fit with least amount of variables).

Comment: On what basis do i remove the variables from the equation to maintain least no of variables?.

Comment: i have updated my question with the summary of my model. please have a look and suggest me on this. thanks in advance

Comment: Stepwise is one automated way to choose a "good" AIC value.  Forward stepwise starts with no variables and 1) adds the variable that has the best fit and 2) calculates the AIC.  At some point, adding the variable with the best fit won't be worth the penalty of adding another variables and the forward stepwise selection will automatically stop.  "both" and "backwards" stepwise regression are variations of this.

Comment: @ Mark Helier - This is what am looking for. How do i accept this as answer?